# TypeScript / Javascript ununderstandable Array behavior

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a strange bug in my Angular code which I can't understand. I don't know whether it is related to the following behavior that I can't understand.

```js
class Foo {
  bar: string;

  constructor(bar: string) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

const fooList: Foo[] = [
  new Foo('A')
];

console.log(fooList[0]);
console.log(fooList);
fooList.forEach(foo => console.log(foo));

fooList[0].bar = 'B';
```

I'm using Angular 8 and when I run it on Firefox I see the following

[image: Console output]

What could it be?

Comment: What's the strange behavior?

Comment: `console.log(fooList)` in the snippet I posted prints "A", when I run the Angular application in my browser it prints "B" as you can see from the screenshot.

Comment: see second console log: *bar: "B"*. @andrea.ge in chrome it shows *bar:"B"* for all console logs. Since they refer to the same object you are changing the value of *bar*.

Comment: @andrea.ge console.logs are not synchronous. There is no guarantee they happen before or after the assignment.

Comment: I am expecting "A" everywhere. If I see any "B", it's beyond my understanding.

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov the assignment happens *after* the objects are logged. OP is expecting synchronous printing and non-live views.

Comment: In case you haven't noticed that your question is closed as a duplicate and as TL;DR: it's caused by a lazy object evaluation in the console. Nothing more, nothing less. It's a console specific curiosity. It has nothing to do with how the code actually behaves.

Comment: thank you very much, I read the other answers. So now I go back to the actual bug using `console.log` properly.